# How to implement delegate for open source browser SVWebViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I understand that for iOS `UIWebView` I can implement `UIWebViewDelegate` and then access the method required.

However for a custom browser [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController), I am confused as to how to implement the delegate method as I tried implementing `UIWebViewDelegate` above and it did not work (The "load" message is not showing at all).

```
class TableInfo: UITableViewController, MWFeedParserDelegate, ENSideMenuDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate{
    var allowLoad = true

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    println("Load")
    return allowLoad
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    allowLoad = false
}
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if hasInternet {
        let item = self.items[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem
        let URL = NSURL(string: item.link)
        let con = SVWebViewController(URL: URL)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(con, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code. Show how you create and setup the `SVWebViewController`. Show how you set its `delegate` property.

Comment: Done, the main library is included in the hyperlink.

Comment: Where do you set the `delegate` property on `con`?